# Sense 240v current flow externally

Tags: gpio, sensor

I have a situation where I suspect my well pump is short-cycling, and I'd like to rig up some sort of sensor that can detect when it comes on and send me an alert. I'm thinking a Pi should be good for this. I'm no Pi expert,  ur I can handle the programming. Where I'm at a loss I'm how I can detect the current flow.

The caveat is I don't want to touch the existing well system... no splicing into anything, for example. So I'm looking for something I can set next to the main power line that runs from the relay box to the well pump. The relay box controls the pump, so when the relay kicks on and the 240v current flows through the line to the pump, I want to detect it externally, just by something being in proximity to the wires.

It seems like a Hall sensor might be what I'm looking for, but I haven't been able to find a good example of now to wire it up with a Pi.

Could someone either point me to a sample design, or if I'm in the wrong track entirely, redirect me appropriately?

Thanks very much!

Comment: what controls the pump? ... how is the pump connected to the controller?

Answer (score 2):

Your description suggests that the sensor you want is an **AC current clamp sensor** - you've probably seen one before. Some current clamp sensors use Hall Effect devices to sense current, others use a ferrite transformer or a [Rogowski coil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogowski_coil). Hall Effect devices are capable of measuring AC and DC, whereas ferrite & Rogwski current sensors will only measure AC. There are a huge number of **current clamps** available in the markets today offering the typical price-performance tradeoffs. I'd suggest that you start with a [fairly broad search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=current+clamp+sensor), to find a unit that meets your voltage & current requirements.

It's not clear from your question why you want to use an RPi, but if you're committed to that, you should look for sensors that have an analog or digital output instead of (or in addition to) a visual display. Once you've found a sensor (or narrowed your candidates to 2 or 3 units), we can help with the interface to the RPi.

Happy shopping & good luck with your project.

Comment: That does help, thank you. Yes, I've seen them before, so I do know what to research (and I appreciate the link for a jumpstart). The only reason I had using an RPi in my head is so that I can get an alert, especially if it's cycling at night as I suspect. But, with your hint, I'm certainly capable of getting a current clamp as you say and hacking it into an RPi (just need to find one that lights an LED or buzzes or something, I'm sure I can hook into that circuit and get it interfaced to the GPIO somehow)... but maybe I'll get lucky and find one that keeps history, that's well on its own).

Comment: That sounds like a good approach. There are many ways to interface with the RPi: GPIO (a digital or analog electrical signal), UART, Bluetooth, etc - and we can help you with any of those (well... BT is a bit *flaky* :)  I'm reasonably sure that you can find a sensor that provides some sort of electrical signal to interface with. WRT the alarm you mentioned: Have you worked out how you're going to implement the alarm?

Comment: And one final thought: You mentioned "`the relay kicks on and the 240v current flows`" ... Have you considered the possibility of monitoring the control signal that energizes the relay? That would tell you when the pump turns on, but wouldn't tell you how much AC current was flowing to the pump.

Comment: I found a clamp on Amazon that connects via BT to a phone app and has history functions for around $40. So, my plan is to use an old Nexus 7 I have (love those things!) and I think that'll do the trick. The control signal comment is a good one, I'll look at that if this doesn't work. To be honest, I didn't analyze the control box, my first and only thought was monitor the power line to the pump itself. I probably should have thought of what you said myself though :) Thanks again!

Comment: @FrankW.Zammetti: Sounds like that should do the trick as long as your phone is within BT range (which isn't that far). Let us know if you hit any snags.